# React-router-V4 render error when using ReactJS new context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-context

I´m trying to use React Router V4 with new React´s context API. Here is my code:

```
class App extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        router: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        module: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        sideMenuConfig: PropTypes.string
    };

    render() {

        let baseName = "/" + this.props.module;

        // This will get my dashboard component, loading context from database
        let navComponent = (
            <MyCustomAppContextProvider>
                <AppContext.Consumer>
                    {context => 
                        <Dashboard
                            context={context}
                            module={this.props.module}
                            router={router}
                            sideMenuConfig={this.props.sideMenuConfig}
                        />
                    }
                </AppContext.Consumer>
            </MyCustomAppContextProvider>
            );

        let routes = null;
        if (!isAuthenticated()) {
            routes = <Auth 
                        baseName={baseName}
                     />;
        } else {
            routes = (
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
                    <Route exact path="/auth" component={Logout} />
                    <Route exact path="/" component={navComponent} />
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/:screen"
                        component={navComponent}
                    />
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/:screen/:action"
                        component={navComponent}
                    />
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/:screen/:action/:id"
                        component={navComponent}
                    />

                    <Route component={PageNotFoundError} />
                </Switch>
            );
        }

        return (
            <BrowserRouter basename={baseName}>
                {routes}
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

`router` contains a router function that will load my screen depending on the navigation path.
`module` is the module name.
`sideMenuConfig` is a json configuration for my side menu.

When trying to run I´m getting the following error from react router:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Check the render method of `Route`.
```

I expect in Dashboard to receive all the props passed plus the match property to run the router.

Comment: Should that be `AppContext.Provider` with a dot? Also what is the point of rendering a `Consumer` as an immediate child of a `Provider`? The error comes from react. Something that you are trying to render is an object. Could you add the stack trace? In which component does it happen?

Comment: This is the new context API notation... Check it out at [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). The `Consumer` grabs context from database to offer to `Provider`. The error seens to be happening inside react-router-v4. No clear stacktrace.

Comment: I know the new api but i don't see any point in using the Provider and the Consumer in the same component. Where do you populate the context with data?

Comment: What does "no clear stack trace" mean? The error happens while rendering a component. Open your browser console and see in which components render that is. This error happens when you try to render a javascript object (you can't render objects). It does not come from react-router.

Comment: For every route `AppContextProvider` will grab context data from database (this data can change so I have to retrieve it on every page load). This context will be offered to my `Dashboard` that will provide navigation and screens depending on loaded `context` (like privileges, username, etc) and router configuration. Can´t see your point here... @trixn you will see no usedfull stack trace data, it´s all pointing to a bundle...

Comment: I´ve added a missing error line. It is in the router....

Comment: So the reason for your error probably is just the typo I was pointing to in my first comment. It has to be `<AppContext.Provider>` not `<AppContextProvider>`. But still using the context api like this makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @trixn, thanks, but you are going the wrong way. `<AppContextProvider>` is a custom component I´ve made. I will change it´s name to avoid confusion.... The error is related to `react-router-v4` receiving a dynamically created component, in my case, using the new context API. Either there is another way to use the context with router or another way to pass the created component to react-router-v4....

Comment: your made the same mistake in your update. i updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not passing a component to `Route`

```
// THIS IS NOT A COMPONENT

let navComponent = (
  <MyCustomAppContextProvider>
    <AppContext.Consumer>
      {context => (
        <Dashboard
          context={context}
          module={this.props.module}
          router={router}
          sideMenuConfig={this.props.sideMenuConfig}
        />
      )}
    </AppContext.Consumer>
  </MyCustomAppContextProvider>
)
```

A component is either a `class` that extends `React.Component` or a function:

```
// THIS IS A COMPONENT 

let NavComponent = props => (
  <MyCustomAppContextProvider>
    <AppContext.Consumer>
      {context => (
        <Dashboard
          context={context}
          module={this.props.module}
          router={router}
          sideMenuConfig={this.props.sideMenuConfig}
        />
      )}
    </AppContext.Consumer>
  </MyCustomAppContextProvider>
)
```

UPDATE to your UPDATE:

You're getting confused about what is a component

```
// THIS IS A COMPONENT
let Foo = props => <div />

// THIS IS NOT A COMPONENT
let Foo = <div />
```

You need to pass a *component* to Route's component prop:

```
let NavComponent = props => <MyCustomAppContextProvider>...

// YES
<Route component={NavComponent} />

// NO
<Route component={<NavComponent />} />
```

Comment: For some other reason the error persists... How is the new component used in the `<Route>` method?

Comment: Yes, I just found out about that. Now it works. Thanks for your precious help, and a nice upvote!

Comment: np, I would take @trixn 's advice though. Your provider / Consumer placement doesn't make very much sense

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me, it was that context api which was causing a conflict. I also had to check every single inner components inside render method to make sure that none of them use context api and has no `this.context` available inside them. I then deleted context api stuff and wrote an alternative react-redux state, no context api, no problem

Answer (score 0):

Check the form you are importing. It is necessary to put the BrowserRouter in the import. Look:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, switch, route } from "react-router-dom";
```